# Using query in Google Sheets, function will not pull over all data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm using the Query function in Google Sheets to pull over data tracking student behavior (includes name, ID, date, grade, etc.) The query function will pull over everything except the letter 'k' in the 'Grade column' (the 'k' is for kindergarten. All other grades are written as numbers, and those are transferring over fine).

Here is a sheet showing the problem I'm having.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gU12f-yG29hgCzB8cc8t8qjejsjYj4dmLx98ozguLEg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I just changed the format - worked great thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the official help article, [QUERY Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

> ### Missing data when you query text and numbers
>
> #### Issue
>
> Use a single data type (text or numbers), when using the QUERY function. If you have mixed data, the query will miss data.
>
> When there is mixed data in a column:
>
> The most common data type will be the data type for the query.   The
>   least common data type will be considered null values and will not be
>   counted in the query.
>
> #### Solution
>
> Set the column number formatting to plain text.